# Oracle - JDC code throwing Array out of bound exception

Tags: jdbc

```
   -------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------

Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at oracle.security.o3logon.C0.r(C0)
    at oracle.security.o3logon.C0.l(C0)
    at oracle.security.o3logon.C1.c(C1)
    at oracle.security.o3logon.O3LoginClientHelper.getEPasswd(O3LoginClientHelper)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.O3log.<init>(O3log.java:289)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.logon(TTC7Protocol.java:251)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:246)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:365)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:260)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at OracleJDBC.main(OracleJDBC.java:29)
```

Code:
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

```
public class OracleJDBC {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

        Connection connection = null;

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system","appdb");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }

}
```

Causing exception :"ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"
Using Oracle 11g XE & Added classes12.jar and ojdc14.jar to libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs when you use a different database driver than what you should.

You are using Jdbc version 9.x. Use 10.x to connect to XE and use ojdbc14.jar while using JDK 1.4 instead of classes12.jar. classes12.jar is typically used with JDK 1.2 & JDK 1.3.

For more see [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/372542)

Comment: You are right Mavroscy i'm done by adding ojdbc6.jar to buildpath i.e. for Oracle 11g release db ..Thanks a lot!